# How to change only one value in a dictionary of numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I am stuck with a problem that I believe to be trivial.

I have a dictionary with 2 entry (simulations). Each entry is another dictionary with 2 entrys (options). Each option is a numpy array.

In a first step I am creating those arrays, so that they are equal in shape for each simulation. In the next step I want to change only one value (in the example: `Sim 1`, `Option_1`, array-element `[0,0]`).

```
simulations = {"Sim 1" : "Sim a",
               "Sim 2" : "Sim b"}

zero_trips = {"Option_1" : np.zeros((2, 2)),
              "Option_2" : np.zeros((2, 2))}

sim_trips = {}
for sim in simulations:
    sim_trips[sim] = zero_trips

print(sim_trips)
sim_trips["Sim 1"]["Option_1"][0,0] += 1
print(sim_trips)
```

But for some reason the Option_1-arrays are changed for every simulation and not just for simulation 1.

```
# 1st output
    {'Sim 1': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
               'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}, 
     'Sim 2': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
               'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}}

# 2nd output
    {'Sim 1': {'Option_1': array([[1., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
               'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}, 
     'Sim 2': {'Option_1': array([[1., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
               'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help?

My desired output looks like this:

```
        {'Sim 1': {'Option_1': array([[1., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
                   'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}, 
         'Sim 2': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
                   'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for this. This is because you're assigning `zero_trips` to each simulation, rather than the value of `zero_trips`. If you edit one of them, all of the `zero_trips` values will change.

**Code:**

```
from copy import deepcopy

simulations = {"Sim 1" : "Sim a",
               "Sim 2" : "Sim b"}

zero_trips = {"Option_1" : np.zeros((2, 2)),
              "Option_2" : np.zeros((2, 2))}

sim_trips = {}
for sim in simulations:
    sim_trips[sim] = deepcopy(zero_trips)

print(sim_trips)
sim_trips["Sim 1"]["Option_1"][0,0] += 1
print(sim_trips)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Sim 1': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]), 
           'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}, 
 'Sim 2': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]),
           'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}}

{'Sim 1': {'Option_1': array([[1., 0.], [0., 0.]]),
           'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}, 
 'Sim 2': {'Option_1': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]),
           'Option_2': array([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])}}
```

Comment: Do you know why does this not work ? `for sim in simulations:
    sim_trips[sim] = zero_trips.copy()`